# how to add active entries to static page

Tags: contextual-help

I want to create new static page (to share news - weblinks) where I will upload everyday interesting entries with web links, my short comments, to news from web with tags and page would something look like:

```
Data 05/02/2017

(tag ) web link :  
My Comment ( optional )  

(tag ) web link : 
My Comment ( optional )

Data 04/02/2017 

(tag ) web link :
My Comment ( optional ) 

etc...
```

- Should I create new data base for this? plugin etc?
- Any idea how this could be implemented?

The idea is t have entry in admin panel and with multiple fields like weblink, info source, comment. Or maybe something like this already exists?

Comment: Hi Greg. Sounds to me like what you want is a regular posts page. Can you tell us a bit more? Do you want to select specific posts to be on the homepage out of all the ones in the website?

Comment: I see. What you could do is have different categories for your posts (like news-links) and use `WP_Query` to show only the latest links in a `front-page.php` file in your theme. Its super standard, but the best way (for me) is usually the one that's easiest to maintain.

Comment: Pedro,
I will have main post page, where i will publish my staff. There will be few categories in it. etc. so this will be standard staff. 
But i want ot have  new link-page, just to share headline news, where i will add new entries when i will find good one. 
And only there the links will be visible as new entries.
The days of publication will splited as shown abouve.  
No links or posts on the main blog page.
So i think that i need new data base to add??
I i guess some plugin where i will have few fields to fill in for each link.
It is clear what i described?

Comment: petro, but the front-page.php is used already for the main posts.
WP_Query could be used but i quess i need new data-base for it?

Comment: Sure. Lets put it this way. When you create a CPT in wordpress, you are using the wp_posts table, which shares the schema of posts and pages. Therefore what you are really doing is creating a sort of separate category for your posts. There is no performance gain. The other option is to create your custom table, which means A LOT of work, since you need to create all CRUD methods from scratch. Its often overkill. This is why I often suggest to keep it simple.

Comment: If you create a category in your posts you can restrict the query to show only that category (if I am not mistaken its the `cat` variable). You style the list as you would any other loop. Its easier to maintain and much faster to build. If you want to separate the link from your content, you can save it as `post_meta` in a separate field [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) makes it super easy, but you can just use the default custom fields.

Comment: You can have as many WP_Queries as you'd like in a page. So you can start with a query to fetch the links, fetch the link post_meta and display it, then do a `wp_reset_postdata` and run the regular query will all the posts.

Comment: but then for every new link i will have new post. I dont want this.
I would prefer to have a plugin ot sth that will be directly add new link-posts to new database=table and then a new function which will read directly from the link-database to the link-page.
could you maybe describe for me process in steps what to do. 
I am new but i learn fast so i do not see problem with this development.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here you go.

I made a wireframe for you to use, which saves links to a custom table and adds a form in the admin page.

Again. I think its wayyyyy overkill. Doing it 'the wordpress way' is a safer bet. But, it was a fun little excersise that I don't get to do often!

I'll copy paste the code below. You'll need to save it to a file in `wp-content` and activate the plugin.

Here is what the admin will look like after the plugin is activated:

[image]

To use it on the front end, you'll have to get the global class and call `read_links_archive( $args )` like so:

```
global $customlinks;
$links = $customlinks->get_links_archive();

foreach ( $links as $link ) {  ... }
```

Also, note the code is very much incomplete! But I've anotated with links whenver possible so it should get you started very well!

**It works like this:**

- There is a CustomLinks class that houses all the CRUD functions ( minus delete, that one's for you to have some fun) and admin rendering magic
- The database is installed when the plugin is activated through a hook
- On construct, it adds the actions to create the database schema and register menu page
- Menu page loads a 'router' that looks for an 'action' post variable, which calls methods accordingly
- At the very end, the class is instantiated into the `$customlinks` variable which you can access with the `global`keyword.

**You'll have to fill in the gaps:**

- Delete method doesn't exist
- There is no interface for the update method
- The save action is unprotected, either by Nonces or capability checks
- `read_links_archive` is doesn't filter by date or has pagination (but its setup to receive arguments)
- You'll need pagination in the admin page
- Make it better all around!

Play around with the code and have fun. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Cheers!

**The code:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom links
 *
 * Plugin Name: Custom links
 * Version: 0.1
 *
 */

class CustomLinks {


  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  function __construct() {

    // add actions

    // install database on activation
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'setup_database') );

    // menu items
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_menu_item' ) );

  }

  /*****************************
          Setup database
  *****************************/

  /**
   * Creates the database schema
   *
   * Hook onto plugin initialize
   *
   * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins
   */
  public function setup_database() {
    // get the wordpress database helper
    global $wpdb;

    // table name
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_links';

    // get colation
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();


    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      ID mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
      link text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );

  }

  /*****************************
          CRUD functions
  *****************************/

  /**
   * Returns a single link
   *
   * @param int $id The link ID
   * @return string|bool The link or false
   */
  public function read_link_single( $id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
      SELECT link
      FROM {$wpdb->prefix}custom_links
      WHERE ID = %d
      LIMIT 1
    ", $id );

    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

    // databse error, return false
    if ( ! $result ) { return false; }

    // return first result
    return $result[0];

  }

  /**
   * Returns all links
   *
   * @param array $args Optional arguments to pass, such as limit or date
   * @return string[]|bool The links or false
   */
  public function read_link_archive( $args = array() ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // default values
    $default = array(
      'limit'   =>  10
    );

    // parses default values
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $default );

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
      SELECT *
      FROM {$wpdb->prefix}custom_links
      LIMIT %d
    ", $args[ 'limit' ] );

    return $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

    // TODO: Pagination, filtering ETC
  }

  /**
   * Creates link, returns ID
   *
   * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row
   * @param string $link The link URL
   * @return int|bool Link unique ID, or false
   */
  public function create_link( $link ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // sanitize link
    $link = esc_url( $link );

    // try to insert
    $result = $wpdb->insert(
      $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_links',
      array(
        'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
        'link' => $link
      )
    );

    // return error
    if ( ! $result ) { return false; }

    // otherwise return id of new row
    return $wpdb->insert_id;

  }

  /**
   * Updates the selected links
   *
   * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows
   * @param int $id The id to update
   * @param string $link The link URL
   * @return bool Update sucessful?
   */
  public function update_link( $id, $link ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'custom_links',
        array(
            'link' => $link,                     // new value string
        ),
        array( 'ID' => $id )                   // condition
    );

    // return update status
    return $result !== false;
  }


  /*****************************
   Display functions for admin
  ******************************/

  /**
   * Adds a menu item for links
   *
   * Hook into admin_menu
   *
   * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/
   */
  public function add_menu_item() {
    add_menu_page(
      'Custom Links',
      'Custom Links',
      'manage_options',
      'custom_links',
      array( $this, 'route_links_page' )
    );
  }

  /**
   * "Route links page"
   */
   public function route_links_page() {

     // check 'action'
     $action = $_POST[ 'action' ] || '';

     // switch here for more pages in the future
     switch ( $action ) {
       case 'save':
        // save action
        $this->save_link();
        $this->render_links_page();
        break;

      default:
        // by default, render links
        $this->render_links_page();
        break;
     }


   }

  /**
   * Renders the link page
   *
   * @param int $page The paginations current page to show
   */
  private function render_links_page( $page = 0 ) {

    // get all links ( 10 by default )
    $links = $this->read_link_archive();

  ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h1>Custom Links</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- links -->
    <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped posts">

      <tbody id="">
        <?php foreach ( $links as $link ) : ?>
          <tr>
            <td><? echo $link->link ?></td>
            <td><? echo $link->time ?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>

      <?php // TODO: Edit and delete link ?>
    </table>

    <!-- add new link -->
    <h2>Add New Link</h2>

    <form action="<?php menu_page_url( 'custom_links' ); ?>" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save">

      <label for="link">Link: </label>
      <input type="text" name="link">

      <?php submit_button( 'Save Link' ); ?>

      <?php // TODO: Protect with Nonce ?>
    </form>
  <?php }

  /**
   * Saves the links and outputs message
   */
  private function save_link() {
    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'link' ] ) ) {
      $result = $this->create_link( esc_url( $_POST[ 'link' ] ) );
    }

    if ( $result ) : ?>
      <div class="notice notice-success">
        <p>Link ID <?php echo $result; ?> saved.</p>
      </div>
    <? else : ?>
      <div class="notice notice-error">
        <p>There was a problem saving the link</p>
      </div>
    <?php endif;
  }

}


/*****************************
        Instantiate
******************************/
$customlinks = new CustomLinks();
```